# CentOS 7 and RAID setup

Tags: centos, raid, hard-drive, lvm

CentOS 7.1 question for Everyone. How would you install a system if it needs to have a standalone disk for all the main folders and an array of 2 disks in RAID1 for a custom folder mount?

- Create the RAID during install and mount it straight away
- Install the system on the standalone disk and create the RAID later?

Which is better in your opinion and why? Which makes it easier to replace a faulty disk?

Answer (score 0):

Both, the only difference is which one you prefer.

For simple software RAID1 you can use the installer as it supports all possible features (it makes sense to do it manually afterwards in RAID10 setup as the installer is lacking features there).
If you choose to do it manually afterwards you will probably re-create the steps that the installer does anyway.

Note that using software RAID1 for only specific directory is bad practice, if you lose the single disk your system will be gone together with your RAID configuration so you will have to install new system and rebuild the RAID1 for that specific directory. A simple CentOS installation requires no more than 10GB of space(20GB in RAID1, if you skip adding swap) so way not use RAID1 for the entire system.

Comment: Wao, really? I didn't know if I mount a RAID1 array in one folder and if one disk fails then the whole system is gone. I have to re-think a bit this. Are you sure about what you've just said? If I install a standard CentOS on a standalone disk, then later create an array with two disks and mount it (let's say to /backup) then the whole system is gone?

Comment: Well yes your system is on the single disk, you are mirroring only /backup so anything else will be gone. Also note that I am taking about the single disk that your system is installed on, if you for example have 3 disks, 1 for the systems and 2 for RAID1 mounted on /backup and lose one of the two disks in RAID1 your system will be fine. But if you lose the single disk you will have to reinstall the system, rescan for the RAID1 configuration and mount it under /backup (those files won't be lost)

Comment: `if you for example have 3 disks, 1 for the systems and 2 for RAID1 mounted on /backup and lose one of the two disks in RAID1 your system will be fine. ` This is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Then I wasn't wrong. I want to RAID only the /backup only, not the system. I don't care for the system if the /backup is untouched. :)

Comment: Just to be clear: You don't need any "configuration" files or such to recreate the RAID1 later, it doesn't matter if the system fails, the backup folder will be fine, RAID is a partition setting. We run the exact same setup (RAID 1 for a backup folder) for years.